# How to add ID3 "cover art" by command line?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, mp3, metadata, id3

I need to add ID3 cover art to some MP3 files.
I need a command line tool (no GUI) but it seems that neither id3 nor id3v2 tools can do it.
Any hint?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An excellent Python application that I routinely use to add cover art to mp3 files is the command line application`eyeD3`. This can be installed from a Terminal as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install eyed3
```

Here is an example of a command to add a cover image named `cover.jpg` to an mp3 file named `test.mp3`:

```
eyeD3 --add-image "cover.jpg:FRONT_COVER" test.mp3
```

See an example below of this at work on my own computer, adding a cover image to an mp3 otherwise empty of meta tags:

```
andrew@ilium~$ eyeD3 --add-image "cover.jpg:FRONT_COVER" test.mp3
test.mp3    [ 946.12 KB ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Adding image cover.jpg
Time: 01:00 MPEG1, Layer III    [ 128 kb/s @ 44100 Hz - Joint stereo ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID3 v2.4:
title: 
artist: 
album: 
album artist: None
track:      
FRONT_COVER Image: [Size: 95788 bytes] [Type: image/jpeg]
Description: 

Writing ID3 version v2.4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
andrew@ilium~$
```

There are *many* other options for adding images although I have given the basic syntax above. Below are these other options:

```
  --add-image IMG_PATH:TYPE[:DESCRIPTION]
                        Add or replace an image. There may be more than one
                        image in a tag, as long as the DESCRIPTION values are
                        unique. The default DESCRIPTION is ''. If PATH begins
                        with 'http[s]://' then it is interpreted as a URL
                        instead of a file containing image data. The TYPE must
                        be one of the following: OTHER, ICON, OTHER_ICON,
                        FRONT_COVER, BACK_COVER, LEAFLET, MEDIA, LEAD_ARTIST,
                        ARTIST, CONDUCTOR, BAND, COMPOSER, LYRICIST,
                        RECORDING_LOCATION, DURING_RECORDING,
                        DURING_PERFORMANCE, VIDEO, BRIGHT_COLORED_FISH,
                        ILLUSTRATION, BAND_LOGO, PUBLISHER_LOGO.
```

**References:**

- [eyeD3: Complex Options (Images)](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/classic_plugin.html#complex-options)

Comment: This is really new to me! So far I've only found GUI tools or some MP3 encoder like lame.  Thanks.

Comment: Seconded, eyeD3 is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a Python script that works for me. Run it with `python script.py audiofile.mp3`.

You will need `mutagen`; install it with `sudo -H pip install mutagen`.

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC, error
import sys
mp3file=sys.argv[1]
audio = MP3(mp3file, ID3=ID3)

try:
   audio.add_tags()
except error:
   pass

audio.tags.add(
   APIC(
      encoding=1,
      mime='image/png',
      type=3,
      desc=u'Cover',
      data=open('/path/to/artwork.png').read()
   )
)
audio.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But this basically equals to "write the program yourself".

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I have *given* you the program. What do you need to write yourself?

Comment: If you read my question not as personal but as a general one, your answer, while a really good one, sounds like "No way, unless you write a program to do so (or youse Jos')".